# Over coming a length restriction

Tags: mesh

I've been working on assets for a game and I've run into a bit of an issue. The game requires that all blender assets be below a specific x length. Changing the coding of the game is unfortunately not possible, would it be possible to overcome said restriction by manipulating the mesh in blender? Is it possible to make the mesh visible beyond said range without violating the restriction?

Comment: Hi Andres, could you provide more context and info on the restriction? May be describe the type of object or scene you're working with. Even better if you have some screenshot with examples of working and non working assets illustrating the length restriction. That would definitely increase the chance of getting an answer!

Comment: also this is more of a gamedev question since I dont think the solution will need some more blender knowledge